# Deploying php page to GitHub Pages

Tags: php, github-pages

I am trying to deploy an index.php page to GitHub Pages. Github Pages says that my site is published at this url, but when I open the link it's giving me an error 404 (page not found).

Comment: it's really impossible for anyone to help you here based on that description of the problem

Comment: Github Page is a static page hosting service, it doesn't support server-side language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub pages does not support server-side code or in other words, it only supports static pages made with HTML, JavaScript, jQuery and CSS only.